# Отображение картинки в отдельном окне

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

хочу отобразить по нажатию на кнопку окно и в нём картинку.

```
def load_photo(event):
    filename=askopenfilename()
    #send photo
    json_string =client.faces_detect(file=(filename))
    #print(json_string)
    c= tk.Tk()

    canvas = Canvas(c,width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'white')
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = filename)
    canvas.create_image(10,10,image = image, anchor = NW)
    #detection eyes
    canvas.create_rectangle(50,50,100,100,width=3,outline='green')
    textbox.insert('1.0',json_string)
    c.mainloop()
```

в итоге создаётся пустое окно и ошибка в консоли

```
TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

на строке

```
canvas.create_image(10,10,image = image, anchor = NW)
```

если делать без создания окна - то оно нормально отображается на главном root окне

Comment: В текущем виде непонятно почему произошла эта ошибка. Попробуйте [создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @gil9red добавил полный код функции

Comment: filename и image валидные?

Comment: @gil9red ну если делать без создания окна с - всё отображается в главном окне нормально

Comment: Все равно, у вас не воспроизводимый пример :) Суть в том, чтобы взять ваш код, запустить его и получить ошибку :) А так, попробуйте заменить `tk.Tk` на `tk.Toplevel`, еще есть вариант `image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=c)`

Comment: @gil9red master=c помогло!В Чем смысл этого аргумента, если я указываю канвасу рисовать на на окне "с" и вызываю картинку уже в конвасе?

Comment: Я ориентировался на этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45395582/5909792 Согласно ему, проблема в окнах, созданных через tk.Tk() -- мол все переменные по умолчанию адресуются к первому Tk, поэтому нужно вызывать master чтобы принудительно указать к какому Tk будет относиться объект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была решена через указание в [ImageTk.PhotoImage](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) параметра `master`:

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=c)
```